# Can I use a mSATA drive to create a Fusion Drive in my iMac?

Tags: imac, fusion-drive

I have a Samsung MZ MPA1280/0D1 128 SSD mSATA drive.

Can I use this to create a Fusion Drive in my 2011 iMac 27" and, if so, what cable will I need in order to connect the mSATA drive properly?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently with [this iFixit upgrade kit](http://www.ifixit.com/Apple-Parts/iMac-Intel-27-Inch-Mid-2011-Dual-Hard-Drive-Kit/IF174-002) you can add a second SATA drive:

```
You'll have two drives as well as a functioning optical drive. All you need is an extra 2.5" SATA drive (not included).
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to mount the SSD and your regular HD into a single volume and imitate a fusion drive. Instructions [here](http://jollyjinx.tumblr.com/post/34638496292/fusion-drive-on-older-macs-yes-since-apple-has). In that article the author used a sata drive, so maybe you could use an [msata to sata](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004YKJ5TE) adaptor.